# How to get a website link from github API?

Tags: github, github-api

Is there a way to get the website link via github api? Currently I don't see it when using the following:

> curl 
> -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" 
> https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/repos

I can get the topics and the description text but not the website (winterbe.com/projects...).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql), and you're looking for the `homepageUrl` field under a given repo. For example, the query below will give all public repositories for a given user, and for each repository, it will give its name, description, and homepage:

```
query MyQuery {
  repositoryOwner(login: "username") {
    repositories(orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC}, first: 100, privacy: PUBLIC) {
      nodes {
        name
        description
        homepageUrl
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unlike the REST api, the GraphQL api requires authentication. You can tinker around with the query [here](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer).

Comment: [a quickstart in graphql](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the JSON REST API as well.

`{{baseUrl}}/api/v3/repositories/{{id}}`

You're looking for the "homepage" property.

Response:

```
{
   "id": "123",
   "node_id": "ABC",
   ...
   "homepage": "https://www.abc123-example.com"
   ...
}
```